# How to connect a bufferSource to Tone's Destination

Tags: typescript, web-audio-api, tonejs

With regular WebAudio, I can connect a bufferSource to destination like so:

```
const audioCtx = new AudioContext()
const bufferSource = audioCtx.createBufferSource()
bufferSource.connect(audioCtx.destination)
```

I thought I could do the same with Tone.js, but this:

```
const audioCtxTone = Tone.context
const bufferSource = audioCtxTone.createBufferSource()
bufferSource.connect(audioCtxTone.destination)
```

give the error *Argument of type '**Destination**' is not assignable to parameter of type '**AudioNode**'.*

What am I doing/thinking wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I can't exactly explain why your code doesn't work. Tone.js uses standardized-audio-context which provides a wrapper around the Web Audio API to make it more compatible across different browsers. Tone.js has it's own very thin wrapper on top of standardized-audio-context. I assume something is going wrong along the way.

But it should work if you use the `context` property of the `AudioBufferSourceNode` instead. It should point to the right `AudioContext`.

```js
const audioContext = Tone.context;
const audioBufferSourceNode = audioContext.createBufferSource();

audioBufferSourceNode.connect(audioBufferSourceNode.context.destination);
```